# remove [" from string is SSIS using derived column

Tags: ssis

I am trying to remove [" from beginning of the string and "] end of the string by using REPLACE function in derived column. But it is giving an error.
I have used the below formula

```
REPLACE(columnanme,"["","")
```

is used in the to remove [" in the beginning of the string. But not working.

Can someone help me on this.
Note: Data is in table and datatype is NTEXT
Regards,
Khatija

Comment: Please make sure to include error messages in your questions.  In this case, NTEXT is not supported as parameter 1 in the `REPLACE` function.  Can this be cast to WSTR with a max of 4000 characters, or could there be data loss?

Comment: I can't cast to WSTR 4000 since it will be a data loss. Sorry I am not able to post a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to escape the " value

so

\”

REPLACE(columnanme,"[\"","")

otherwise it sees the " in the middle as the closing quote and you have an invalid statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . It is not working since it NTEXT datatype

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to remove [" from beginning of the string and "] end of the string

Supposing that we reliably have brackets and quotes wrapping the data, the simplest approach would be to use substring.  This would be easier to do in SQL:

```
UPDATE myTable SET columnname = SUBSTRING(columnname, 3, LEN(columnname) -4)
WHERE columnname LIKE '["%"]'
```

If you want to do this in SSIS, you'll need to use a script component transformation to avoid data loss when converting the value to a string.  Select the column you want to work with and set the usage type to `ReadWrite`:

[image]

In the script, I have added a method `GetNewString`, which converts the blob to a string and strips the unwanted characters.  You can also use `Replace` or `Regex.Replace` if that makes more sense.

In the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method, we convert the columns data, reset the blob and then add the new value:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var input = GetNewString(Row.columname);
    Row.columname.ResetBlobData();
    Row.columname.AddBlobData(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
}

public string GetNewString(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn blobColumn)
{
    if (blobColumn.IsNull)
        return string.Empty;

    var blobData = blobColumn.GetBlobData(0, (int)blobColumn.Length);
    var stringData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blobData);
    stringData = stringData.Substring(2, stringData.Length - 4);
    return stringData;
}
```